# Displaying image from facebook graph appears margined in the top. Why?

Tags: html, css, facebook, image

Why when I set image `src` from `facebook` picture, the image is margined top (there is a blank space at the top)?

here is the html code for img

```
 $('.raters-div').append("<div class='rater-img'><div class='rate-value'>"+value+
   "</div><img src='https://graph.facebook.com/"+user+"/picture' class='img123' /></div>");
```

css style

```
.rater-img{
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 1px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
.img123{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:30px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.rate-value{
    top: 17px;
    right: 16px;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 11px;
    width: 11px;
    z-index: 500;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you're using `vertical-align: top` and your image is by default `display: inline`? Remove that line or set it to `vertical-align: middle` to center it vertically.

The blank space could be because `.rate-value` has `padding: 1px;`

Comment: Also, post some html. Hard to tell what your exact problem is.